# ASP.NET Webforms: How can I write an entire HTML document to a new browser window?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Given I have contained within a string an entire HTML document, how can I launch a new browser window, and then inject the html into that instance so that the new window renders the document?

I've found so many examples on the web that simply do not work. I'm a middle tier guy, so I'm weak on the web/javascript stuff.

UPDATE: Here's a snippet of code that shows what I'm trying to do

```
void Display()
{

    string javascript = string.Empty;
    javascript += "<script type='text/javascript'>";
    javascript += "var win = window.open('', '', '');";
    javascript += "win.document.open();";
    javascript += "win.document.write('{0}');"; //<------Notice I have a format parameter placed within the call to document.Write
    javascript += "win.document.close();";
    javascript += "win.focus();";
    javascript += "</script" + ">";

    // this.DisplayableDocumentation is an IEnumerable of strings. Each string contains an entire
    // HTML document. Ultimately, I want to launch a new window for each document.
    this.DisplayableDocumentation
        .ForEach(document =>
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(string.Format(javascript, document));

        });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void Display() {
     var i = 0;
     var javascript = "<script type='text/javascript'>";
     DisplayableDocumentation
     .ForEach(document =>
            {
                i++;
                Response.Write(String.Format("<input id='txt{1}' type='text' value='{0}' style='display:none;'/>", Server.HtmlEncode(document), i));
                javascript += String.Format(@"
var win{1} = window.open('', '', '');
win{1}.document.open();
win{1}.document.write(document.getElementById('txt{1}').value); 
win{1}.document.close();
win{1}.focus();
", document, i);
            });
            javascript += "</" + "script>";
            RegisterStartupScript("javascript", javascript);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, I'm not successful when using your example. The result is a blank page, and when I view the page source code, I see the call to document.write along with the entire HTML that I passed into the call. I'll update my original post with a code example.

Comment: Is there a limit to what can be passed into document.write()? When I pass in a small snippet of html, all works fine. When I pass in an entire HTML document via a string variable, it doesn't work at all.

Comment: Thanks! The above code has progressed me forward, but unfortunately, javascript seems incapable of processing the html that I pass to document.write(). I get a javascript error 'Unterminated string constant'.

ASP.net's Response.Write has no problem rendering the html, so this tells me that the HTML is well formed enough, and therefore should be rendered. But then again, what do I know, I'm not a web guy. :)

Answer (score 0):

Put the string somewhere so you can reference it from another page... or rather, another handler. Then set the address of your new window to use this handler as it's href.